# React Bootstrap accordion defaultActiveKey="0" not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

currently I'm using react bootstrap accordion and i have up to 6 level nested accordion and i want that main parent accordion should be expanded by default. i have tried defaultActiveKey but still its not working. i have tried with state also but still facing same problem.

is there anything wrong in my code?

here is my code snippet

```
 <Nav
      className="sidebar__menu position-fixed"
      style={{
        minWidth: '350px',
        background: '#f5f8f9',
        height: '100%',
        overflowY: 'auto',
      }}
    >
      {sideBarCategory?.children?.map((navGroup, index) => (
        <Accordion
          className="customAccordion w-100"
          key={navGroup.id}
          defaultActiveKey={index === 0 ? 0 : null}
        >
          <Accordion.Header>
            <Link
              aria-expanded="true"
              style={{ maxWidth: '220px' }}
              className="accordionHeader"
              to={navGroup.path}
            >
              {navGroup.title.toUpperCase()}
            </Link>
          </Accordion.Header>
          <Accordion.Body>
            {navGroup.children?.map((page) => (
              <NavGroupMenuItem
                style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word', marginLeft: '5px' }}
                key={page.id}
              >
                {page.children?.length ? (
                  <NestedAccordion page={page} />
                ) : (
                  <Link
                    to={page.path}
                    style={{ maxWidth: '250px', wordBreak: 'break-word' }}
                  >
                    {page.title}
                  </Link>
                )}
              </NavGroupMenuItem>
            ))}
          </Accordion.Body>
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </Nav>


    const NestedAccordion = ({ page }) => {
  const renderPages = (pages) => {
    return pages?.map((page) => (
      <NavGroupMenuItem
        style={{ wordWrap: 'break-word', marginLeft: '5px' }}
        key={page.id}
      >
        {Array.isArray(page.children) && page.children.length > 0 ? (
          <Accordion className="nested-accordion">
            <Accordion.Header style={{ marginLeft: '5px' }}>
              <Link
                to={page.path}
                style={{ maxWidth: '250px', wordBreak: 'break-word' }}
              >
                {page.title}
              </Link>
            </Accordion.Header>
            <Accordion.Body>{renderPages(page.children)}</Accordion.Body>
          </Accordion>
        ) : (
          <Link
            to={page.path}
            style={{ maxWidth: '200px', wordBreak: 'break-word' }}
          >
            {page.title}
          </Link>
        )}
      </NavGroupMenuItem>
    ))
  }

  return (
    <Accordion className="nested-accordion">
      <Accordion.Header style={{ marginLeft: '5px' }}>
        <Link
          to={page.path}
          style={{ maxWidth: '250px', wordBreak: 'break-word' }}
        >
          {page.title}
        </Link>
      </Accordion.Header>
      <Accordion.Body>{renderPages(page.children)}</Accordion.Body>
    </Accordion>
  )
}
```